# QML WebView not selectable?

Tags: qt, qml

I have the latest Qt, also, I'm trying out `QtWebKit.experimental`, so, not to use it is not a limitation. I want to be able to select text from my `WebView`, or even, be able to capture those events, anyway, a standard `WebView` like the following is not allowing me to select text from it, I try to, but no selection happens, what should I do to have a selectable `WebView`?

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtWebKit 3.0
import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    width: 500
    height: 500
    x: (Screen.width - width) / 2
    y: (Screen.height - height) / 2
    color: "transparent"

    WebView {
        objectName: "html"
        anchors.fill: parent
        experimental.transparentBackground: true
        focus: true
        Keys.onEscapePressed: Qt.quit()
    }
}
```

NOTICE: I'm manipulating the elements outside the QML file, for example, I'm loading HTML content in the `WebView` through `loadHtml`.

Comment: I think there is no way to do it right now, previous version allowed it by setting WebView::pressGrabTime. hope you'll find a solution or wait for a new releases.

Answer (score 2):

from reading this (src : [QML WebView Element Qt 4.8](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-webview.html#details))

**User Interaction and Navigation**

By default, certain mouse and touch events are delivered to other items in preference to the Web content. For example, when a scrolling view is created by placing a WebView in a Flickable, move events are delivered to the Flickable so that the user can scroll the page. This prevents the user from accidentally selecting text in a Web page instead of scrolling.
The `pressGrabTime` property defines the time the user must touch or press a mouse button over the `WebView` before the Web content will receive the move events it needs to select text and images.
When this item has keyboard focus, all keyboard input will be sent directly to the Web page within.

**Qt 5.x** doesn't have the `WebView::pressGrabTime` and as I read and watched some Qt developper days videos talking about the changes of QtWebEngine and that in future releases of Qt, **webkit** will be replaced by **Google's Chromium web engine** ...